# Change default colors in a pie highchart angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I want to change default colors of a Highchart pie chart. The chart will be generated dynamically, and I don't know how many slices will be in my pie chart. Because of that, I would like to use an array of colors, called $scope.ColorArr, and change default colors of the Highchart pie. How can I do that? Thank you in advance for any help. Below is my code for generating the pie chart:

```
dataService.getAll('InternationalReportTest', 'GetAll', {}, function (res) {
        $scope.NeoRespSuppLastYearMode = res.data;       
        $scope.AuxArray = [];
        $scope.MainArray = [];
        $scope.ColorArr = ['#34CBD3', '#D334CE', '#E94B3B', '#8AD5E7', '#F8C471', '#34D376'];
        var log = [];
        var i = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.NeoRespSuppLastYearMode, function (oneCase) {           
            $scope.AuxArray.push(oneCase.Mode, oneCase.TotRuns, $scope.ColorArr[i])
            $scope.MainArray.push($scope.AuxArray);
            $scope.AuxArray = [];
            i = i + 1;
        }, log);

    });
    $scope.createChart = function () {

        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false

                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Neonatal Respiratory Support Last Year Mode.'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Modes',               
                data: $scope.MainArray,
                color: $scope.ColorArr
            }],

            loading: true
        })};
```

Comment: You need to set the highchart.color array not set the series.color to an array.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Please write me how to set  Highchart.color array and where?

Comment: You have a typo: `color: $scope.ColorArr` -> `colors: $scope.ColorArr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full write up. You are trying to set an individual series' color to an array of colors. This will not work. What you need to do is set the highcharts options [`colors`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors) array.
So you would have something like this:

```
$scope.createChart = function () {

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        colors: $scope.ColorArr,
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false

            },

            title: {
                text: 'Neonatal Respiratory Support Last Year Mode.'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Modes',               
            data: $scope.MainArray
        }],

        loading: true
    })};
```

Comment: Actually, it should work, but should be `colors` not `color`, as per [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.colors).

Comment: Thank you both!! . Both ways work!! Thank you very much again :)